# table adds extra pixels in firefox

Tags: html, css

I just started creating a website for a darts organisation but I'm encountering some problems in my table layout.

I made a table with a table-layout fixed and 978px width.
When I take a look in firefox it somehow for unknown reason always adds another 8px. In safari everything works perfect.
I have no idea what is happening here.

I made the web with the problem available on the link below.
Any suggestions is welcome.

```css
.dt
{
    margin: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.dt th
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    color: #5197fc;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dt td
{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #cdcdcd;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table runat="server" style="width: 978px;" class="dt">
    <tr runat="server">
        <th runat="server" class="left" style="width: 511px">Naam</th>
        <th runat="server" class="left" style="width: 152px">Tel/Gsm</th>
        <th runat="server" class="left" style="width: 252px">Email</th>
        <th runat="server" class="left" style="width: 38px"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr runat="server">
        <td runat="server" style="width: 511px"></td>
        <td runat="server" style="width: 152px"></td>
        <td runat="server" style="width: 252px"></td>
        <td runat="server" style="width: 38px">
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="EditAccount" ImageUrl="~/Images/pencil.png" CommandName="EditAccount" Width="16px" Height="16px" />
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="DeleteAccount" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" CommandName="DeleteAccount" Width="16px" Height="16px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Check problem here](http://test.dartsgent.be/Manager/AccountManager.aspx)

Type an A in the textbox and press search to see the problem.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post but not sure if same results will occure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem in multiple ways.
I have set border collapse to collapse and adjusted the width of all table cell except the width of the last table cell of each row.
for some reason firefox doesn't ever give the actuall width of the cells you asked for. it always adds or retracts some the width which shows weird behavior.

Thats why I removed the entire table and switch to div with "display: table".
This doesn't give me those weird behavior problems.

```css
.dt {
    display: table;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.dt .th {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    color: #5197fc;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dt .td {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #cdcdcd;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <div class="dt" style="width: 960px">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="th" style="width: 500px">Naam</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 150px">Tel/Gsm</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 250px">Email</div>
        <div class="th" style="width: 60px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 500px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 150px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 250px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 60px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `border-spacing: 5px;` on the `dt` elements. Decreasing that value should decrease the amount of "extra pixels".

Comment: there are 4 cells in the table and I have taken 5 times 5 pixels into account. its already calculated into my table. safari doesn't seem to have the problems. that browsers show the correct table width.

Answer (score 0):

Adding border-collapse: collapse; should fix your problem

Comment: I made the choice to make border-collapse: seperate; I calculated every cell with a calculater to get the correct width. I took the cell spacing into account.

511px + 152px + 252px + 38px + (5 x 5px border spacing) = 978px

Comment: Please reduce your total width to 953 including 5*5px border and check what happens. You should have probably added some extra pixals somewhere as the code you provided seems incomplete what is class left doing?

Comment: Also try border-collapse: collapse; instead of border-collapse: separate;

Comment: left just put text-align left to the header cell. because the table header placed all text in the middle. I made a seperate class for it because I don't want all the text on the left for the table headers.

Comment: as you said I adjust my table to made my borders collapse but the results are exactly the same. I also tried your example te reduce total width but no results.

Comment: Please play around with the width for example when I reduced the width 509px + 150px + 250px + 36px  it worked for me

Comment: I tried this before. the problem is that IE, Firefox, Opera and Chrome is showing 8 more pixels while safari is showing the correct behavior. which means when I adapt the width to firefox then safari won't show the correct width anymore. I need the width to behave correct on all browsers. the options you give me are work arounds but no fix. If I just knew whats causing this bug to happen.